# Check If a substring is in a string ignoring uppercase, lowercase and special characters?

Tags: java, string, substring, contains

I'm trying to check if a phrase like "Homemade Pizza!" contains a string like "pizza", BUT I want it to always be true, **it doesn't matter if it's Pizza or pizza or Pizza! or pizza!**

**I'll explain the code:**

`recipesFounded` is an array that contains the title, description, etc. That's why I put `recipesFounded.get(i).getTitle()`.

The problem is that I have the "Homemade Pizza!" string, so If I search "Pizza!" it's good because the recipe is added in the `trueOnes` new recipe list , but if I search pizza (without mayus P and !) it doesn't.

The word is the string that I want to search (*pizza, Pizza!...*)

```
for (int i=0; i < recipesFounded.size(); i++) {
    if (recipesFounded.get(i).getTitle().contains(word)) {
       trueOnes.add(recipesFounded.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: lowercase the title and then check for contains. Lowercasing/Uppercasing both sides of comparison should solve the problem

Comment: If your title is "`something Pizza`" and the search word is "`pizza!`", what do you want the result be?

Comment: I want it to be true!, I'm trying now to quit the special characters and do the lowercasing to solve it! I will post it if that resolves it

Comment: Replace all "special" characters with "" (i.e.remove them), bring both strings to the same case, and then  `contains` will work.

Comment: If you search for `"Made! pi?"`, should that match against `"Homemade Pizza!"`? Should `"PI, MADE."` match? Asked another way, how must pre-processing of the search string should be done to prepare for the search, and how complex can it be?

Comment: I removed every single special character like WJS said!

Comment: No no, Andreas don't worry haha, that's very complex omg, If I search home or made it will be false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `toLowerCase` method of `String`

```
word = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]","").toLowerCase(); // keep only letters
```

Per **Andreas** suggestion, convert word to lower case before looping.  It is more efficient.

```
for (int i=0; i < recipesFounded.size(); i++) {
    if (recipesFounded.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase()
              .contains(word)) {
       trueOnes.add(recipesFounded.get(i));
    }
}
```

Since `List` implements the `iterable` interface, you can do it like this.  It presumes that you are using a class called `Recipe`

```
for (Recipe recipe : recipesFounded) {
    if (recipe.getTitle().toLowerCase()
            .contains(word)) {
       trueOnes.add(recipe);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't call `word.toLowerCase()` in the first block. In the second block, you should do that before the loop.

Comment: @MimiAshv Yeah!  One who makes lots of mistakes.

Comment: @WJS You got there, eventually, with a little guidance. Nice answer. +1. Now see how it should really be done for [enhanced matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60469052/5221149) prowess.  *(only for people who want to go that extra mile)*

Comment: This answer adds no value proposition would prefer @Andreas answer instead. This looks like aggregation of all comments

Comment: @hamlet *This answer adds no value...*.  It would appear we have something in common.

Answer (score 2):

In order to search for letters/digits in the given order, ignoring upper- vs lowercase, spaces, and special characters, it would likely be best to convert the search string into a *regular expression*.

To allow search string `"foobar"` to match against `"Foo-Bar"`, we need to allow special characters between any alphanumeric characters.

For full Unicode support, we will use [`\p{Alnum}`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix) and flags [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS), [`CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE), and [`UNICODE_CASE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE), or rather uppercase `P` for not-alphanum.

To match e.g. `A` with `Á`, we also *decompose* the Unicode characters, using [`Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html).

Here is an example of how to do that:

```
static List<String> search(List<String> texts, String word) {
    String regex = Normalizer.normalize(word, Normalizer.Form.NFD) // e.g. "Á"  ->  "A\u0301"
            .replaceAll("(?U)\\P{Alnum}+", "")                     // e.g. "I'm!"  ->  "Im"
            .replaceAll("(?<=.)(?=.)", "\\\\P{Alnum}*"); // insert '\\P{Alnum}*' between all characters 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS |
                                       Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    List<String> trueOnes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String text : texts) {
        if (p.matcher(Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD)).find()) {
            trueOnes.add(text);
        }
    }
    return trueOnes;
}
```

*Tests*

```
List<String> texts = List.of("Homemade Pizza!", "Dessert", "Pizza Hut", "Potato-Söûp", "O'Malleys Ale");
System.out.println(search(texts, "pizza"));    // [Homemade Pizza!, Pizza Hut]
System.out.println(search(texts, "made, pi")); // [Homemade Pizza!]
System.out.println(search(texts, "ömÁl"));     // [O'Malleys Ale]
System.out.println(search(texts, "TOSO"));     // [Potato-Söûp]
```